# Is there a way to view the current close votes on a question without voting yourself?

Tags: support, closing

Sometimes I run across a question that has close votes, and I don't really have any idea why. Apparently the person who left the vote thought it was pretty clear, because they didn't leave a comment.

When this happens, I'd like to view the close votes to see what reason they used. This can be helpful in realizing a problem I didn't notice before, or in leaving a comment for the author to help them improve the post.

Is there any way to view the close vote reasons on a post with some votes, but not enough to actually be closed?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply click close and navigate to the places that have votes to view which ones. In the following pictures you can see which votes have been cast, but I have not actually voted yet, and I can simply close the window to navigate away.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's simple enough, thanks.

Comment: No problem @DCShannon